# How to add a sort function to an array through a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array being printed as follows:

```
<font color="red">
<ol>
  <% @seller.customers.uniq{|t| t.customer_id }.each do |su| %>
  <li><%= su.name %> <%= su.money.sum(:sum) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ol> 
</font>
```

which prints a list of all the sellers' customers only once with the total value of their spend with the seller.

I wish to sort the array descending based on the value of their spend `su.money.sum(:sum)`. I tried using `.sort { |a, b| b <==> a}` after both `each` and `su.money.sum(:sum)`, but both throw up errors.

Could anyone be so kind as to shed some light on how it would be achieved?

Comment: What do you mean that they throw up areas?

Comment: Oops, meant errors. The errors are NoMethodErrors, still getting them after implementing the first answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using `sort_by` http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by

```
@seller.customers.uniq{|t| t.customer_id }.sort_by{|t| t.money.sum(:sum)}.reverse
```

BTW,  I think the best approach is do it in model or DB level.

Comment: Thanks - this almost worked, but I swapped out .inverse for .reverse :-)

Comment: My bad. I did it in the fly